# Double quotes inside Scala block comments?

Tags: scala

I found a pretty weird thing that I cannot write double quote inside Scala block comment(/**/), I got an error said:

> IO error while decoding xxxx.scala
>   with UTF-8

If I change the double quote to single quote, it compiles fine.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 98.231 with a nightly build Scala plugin.

So what problem could it be?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error in REPL. So I'd guess that the problem is with IntelliJ and/or the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Agl, I am also thinking of it the same.

Comment: I would guess you have a unicode curly quote. If you want to use unicode, i recommend to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the IntelliJ vmoptions file, and set your File Encodings in your IDE settings to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer so that the question can be closed. All kudos to @retronym.

I would guess you have a unicode curly quote. If you want to use unicode, i recommend to add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the IntelliJ `vmoptions` file, and set your File Encodings in your IDE settings to UTF-8.